# Aren't the Nicolaitans the guys who formed the Roman Catholic Church?

Tags: church-history

Aren't the Nicolaitans the guys who formed the Roman Catholic Church? It seems to me to be so. I mean the practice of ruling over the laity is very strong in that church, and it even is a practice amongst many "reformed" and protestant churches.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "ruling over the laity"?

Comment: This reads like an argument disguised as a question. The association is something you seem to have made yourself with no justification and seems designed to insult other Christians. If you could provide some actual support, or rephrase it as "are there modern day churches descended from the Nicolaitans" then it might be an acceptable question.

Comment: @MattGutting I believe I voted "primarily opinion based". Your answer is good, but see the other two this question solicited and they are both just as valid an answer as yours.

Comment: @fredsbend I disagree; because the thrust of my answer was to say "Here is specific authoritative evidence to state that there is no evidence." To the extent the others provide authoritative evidence, their answers - the answers supported by the evidence they provide - agree with mine, or (in the case of the citation of the Catholic Encyclopedia) disagree with the evidence cited. I don't understand how the three answers are (a) different, and simultaneously (b) valid in their differences.

Comment: Good answer here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/65656/who-are-the-nicholaitans?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 11):

*Nicolaism* refers to one or more groups of doctrines, apparently held by a group or groups founded by a Nicolaus, Nicolas, or Nikolaos (depending on exactly how you Anglicize the Greek name). There are a couple of these mentioned in the very early church, but it's unclear what exactly the content of the heresy is. You refer to "the practice of ruling over the laity", apparently with regard to the etymology of *Nikolaos*—Greek *nikē* "victory" + *laos* "people"; though if the name of the sect was taken from the name of its founder, rather than from a description of its doctrines, then this association fails and the sect should not **necessarily** be associated with "ruling over the laity".

The sect appears to be mentioned in Revelation 2:6,15:

> you hate the works of the Nicolaitans, which I also hate. (v. 6)
>
> you also have some people who hold to the teaching of [the] Nicolaitans. (v. 15)

([New American Bible](http://usccb.org/bible/revelation/2:6))

but there is no description of what the works or teaching of the Nicolaitans is, nor why they should be hated.

In his edition of Irenaeus' *Libros quinque adversus haereses* (*Five Books Against Heresies*), W. Wigan Harvey [states](https://books.google.com/books?id=NMlMAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=adversus+haereses&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tDUlVaOeH-mHsQTJi4H4Dg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Nicolaitans&f=false):

> The Nicolaitans taught the complete indifference of human actions in a moral point of view. ... Another hateful feature of this heresy was the assertion, that in times of persecution, principle might be ignored, and conformity rendered to mysteries however abominable, and rites however impure.

Harvey makes clear his opinion (which he bases on writings of Clement of Alexandria) that this sect gets its name from Nicolas (Nicholas) of Antioch, one of the seven deacons described in Acts 6:

> "Brothers, select from among you seven reputable men, filled with the Spirit and wisdom, whom we shall appoint to this task, whereas we shall devote ourselves to prayer and to the ministry of the word." The proposal was acceptable to the whole community, so they chose Stephen, a man filled with faith and the holy Spirit, also Philip, Prochorus, Nicanor, Timon, Parmenas, and Nicholas of Antioch, a convert to Judaism.

(Acts 6:3–5; [NABRE](http://usccb.org/bible/acts/6:3))

If this is indeed the case, as I mentioned above, the name "Nicolaitans" should be associated not with "ruling over the laity" but simply with the (birth-)name "Nicolas".

There is no evidence that this group evolved into the modern Catholic Church; in fact, Eusebius states in his [*History of the Church*](https://books.google.com/books?id=taagmnUcsD8C&pg=PT453&dq=Eusebius+Nicolaitans&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sDolVZmOG67msATjtoDgDg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Eusebius%20Nicolaitans&f=false) that the sect "lasted for a very short time".

Answer (score -1):

As a Catholic Sure hope that Jesus Is not mad at the institution of the Catholic Church. After all their is a hierarchy in the our Church. Pope, Cardinal and Bishop , Priest. A 2000 year institution with sacraments and rules and regulations
Some very corruptled Priests, Bishops, cardinals have  been in the Church for centuries.
I look towards the Catholic  Saints:Francis of Assis a’Thomas Aquinas ,and their relationship to the Church for guidance.

Comment: Richard, welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  To find out how we are different to other sites, and what makes a good and acceptable answer, please take our tour: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score -5):

**Aren't the Nicolaitans the guys who formed the Roman Catholic Church?**

For a time the Nicolaitans were thought to be followers of a guy named Nicholas. Catholic scholarship (which you would think had the greatest reason to support such a view) has found this to not be supported.

http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/11067a.htm

I think we can see in human nature both the desire to lead and the desire to be led. Consider the role of the imam in Shiite Islam.

There is that of our flesh that pollutes our worship and practice of Christianity. Christianity was supposed to be us individually asking God what he wanted us to do. It all to often became us asking a priest what we collectively had to do.

As a general rule, I tend against things like conspiracy theories if only because they imply competence. I do not see the Catholic church as perpetrators of a scheme of enslave Christians. Rather I see in Catholicism, as well as almost all denominations, the common tendency of humans to want the comfort of being assured they are on their way to heaven with the minimal amount of effort on their part.

An alternative translation of the Hebrews 13:17a verse might be, "Stop resisting and allow yourselves to be persuaded by those you have chosen to follow". This gives a different view of the relationship between teacher and seeker than the use of the word "obey".

The guy or guys with power (nikos) often change Christianity into an organizational system of rules. They tell Christians that their relationship with God is through the organizational system and that is primarily following the rules. This is what was happening in Galatia and why so many Christians end up like the Pharisees.

Comment: The first part of this is useful and helpful information.  The second part is unsupported personal opinion (I think.  Support it if it's not, I could totally be wrong here).  Trim the bad stuff.

Comment: If we cut the fat from this answer, we are left with a short comment and a link.